# Nginx scripts executed as www-data

Tags: php, nginx

I'm triyng to execute a bash script with PHP using a Nginx web server. For what I'm doing, it has to be executed as "myuser" and not as "www-data" (cause it doesn't work when executed as "www-data").

I don't have any ideas on how to do it. I've change "user www-data;" in "user myuser;" in /etc/nginx.conf but still the same problem.

Any ideas ?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

There are generally four solution strategies for this requirement:

1. use php as cgi scipting engine which allows use the file systems suid or guid bits to switch the effective user id. However this is extremely insecure, you really have to secure your webserver.
2. take a look at the sudo module php offers.
3. you can start a background process from php which uses one of the above ideas
4. you can fix your stuff so that it works with the current user id. Yes, that IS possible.

Answer (score 2):

> cause it doesn't work when executed as "www-data"

So change the ownership of the script.

```
chown www-data:www-data scriptName.sh
```

Comment: Is it secure to do that ?

Comment: This only helps if the reason why "it doesn't work" is because of restrictive permissions on the script itself. That is actually not typically the case, except if you take specific actions towards that.

Comment: @Boris I think it would be more secure than running nginx with elevated permissions. But as arkascha says it may not solve the problem. for example if you were trying to reboot the server that would not be allowed

Answer (score 0):

Try to edit these files

1. nginx.conf  ( sudo nano /etc/nginx/nginx.conf )

> user YOUR_USER YOUR_GROUP;
>
> ```
> worker_processes 4;
>
> pid /run/nginx.pid;
> ```

1. php5-fpm user ( sudo nano /etc/php5/fpm/pool.d/www.conf )

> user = www-data
>
> group = www-data

and

```
listen.owner = www-data
listen.group = www-data
```

Then

```
sudo /etc/init.d/nginx restart
```

and

```
sudo /etc/init.d/php5-fpm restart
```

I hope it helps.